# Парсинг динамического списка с запоминанием индекса

Tags: python, selenium

ВПроект на python с библиотекой selenium.

При пасинге динамического списка, например, списка подписчиков инстаграм, после скроллинга скрипт сканирует обратно весь список. Как сделать так, чтобы до скроллинга он запомнил индекс последнего пользователя, и после того как пролистает и откроются новые пользователи, он начинал парсинг со следующего?

Comment: Не надо сразу парсить. При открытий страницы скролишь до упора и уже спарсишь всех пользователей.

Comment: Вот именно нет мне надо n-ное количество которое каждый раз задается. Так как вы предложили это Элементарно, Ватсон)